# How to fix AttributeError: type object 'CookieJar' has no attribute 'LWPCookieJar'?

Tags: python, mechanize, cookiejar, cookielib

I am using cookielib(cookiejar named now in Python3) and mechanize.

I am importing this way

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mechanize
try:
    from cookielib import Cookie, CookieJar         
except ImportError:
    from http.cookiejar import Cookie, CookieJar as cookielib
```

but I keep getting this error **(AttributeError: type object 'CookieJar' has no attribute 'LWPCookieJar')** at this point of my code

```py
# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: On an `ImportError` cookielib is bound to the `CookieJar` class. `WPCookieJar` is a member of the `http.cookiejar` module not the `CookieJar` class

Comment: @IainShelvington you mean I should also import LWPCookieJar on its own?

Answer (score 0):

You can import `http.cookiejar` as `cookielib` when using python 3, they have almost the exact same interface.

```
try:
    import cookielib         
except ImportError:
    from http import cookiejar as cookielib

# Now you can use cookielib.LWPCookieJar no matter what version of python you're using
cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
cookielib.CookieJar()  # or the other classes
```